# How can I make a car follow the terrain in a 2D (side-view) game?

Tags: 2d, algorithm, physics

I'd like to create a game where a car drives over a 2D terrain.
Which algorithm to use so the car will follow the mountain incline?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Model the road, so that the car cannot drive off the road? What's the deal with the mountain? Is there anything special regarding the mountain, compared to a "regular" road?

Comment: its road you are right , im looking for way to drow aroad , then 
the car be able to drive . something like this :
http://www.gamesfreak.net/games/4-Wheel-Madness_253.html

Comment: Google "Perlin noise" for terrain generation, as for the other part of the question, I really don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game you linked to in your comment most likely uses a physics-engine like [Box2D (flash port)](http://www.box2dflash.org/) for the car physics. So the basic steps are: Create a car body with connected wheels (use joints) and use either a procedural approach or a level editor to create the terrain.

The car following the terrain will be handled by the physics-engine if you set things up correctly.